# Mix normal method calls with messages when using Actors?

Tags: scala, lift, actor

I'm writing a comet application in lift and some of my actors have references to other actors, eg user A has actor B which has a variable storing actor C which is associated with user D.

Some user actions by A should result in their actor B sending a message to actor C.

These things are triggered by user A.

My question is, is it ok to call regular methods on the actor B which result in it sending a message to C, or should I instead be sending a message to A which it receives and then sends the message to B.

To put it in code, is this kind of thing ok:

```
//in some snippet:
val actorB: ActorB = session.map(.findCometActor(...))
"#some-button" #> SHtml.ajaxInvoke(() => actorB.sendIt(777)) //is this ok?

//the actors:
case class MyMessage(someInt: Int, someString: String)
class ActorB extends CometActor {
  private var someString = ""
  private var otherActor: Box[CometActor] = Empty

  def sendIt(someInt: Int) = otherActor ! MyMessage(someInt, someString)
}
class ActorC extends CometActor {
  def lowPriority = {
    case MyMessage(num, str) => println(num + str)
  }
}
```

Or should the snippet code be sending a message to actor B which will then send a message to actor C rather than calling `actorB.sendIt(777)` directly?

**Edit**: Just to confirm, there are no technical problems with doing this, it is more about style and hopefully making it easier to make the code correct. Is that right?

Comment: In case it is not completely clear from the two answers already given, the answer is: No, don't call methods on actors. Send them messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of the most critical feature of the actor model, is the fact that the processing of each incoming message update the actor state *atomically*. If you call directly a method, this atomicity will be broken and you will face big complications, like handling the coordination yourself or using explicit locks.

Answer (score 1):

Don't call it directly - even if it looks OK, which this doesn't really.  If you're going to access `someString` you should protect it somehow with a lock and this doesn't.

With Actors, in general, use the Actor paradigm.  It's staying in the paradigm that makes your code easy to reason about ... this isn't so easy to reason about and as it gets more complex, it will get worse.  Send a message to B that tells B to send a message to C, as you've indicated.